# Python - Image to Hex

Tags: python, hex

На Python написана функция, которая преобразовывает картинку в HEX.

```
def img_to_hex():
    string = ''
    image = ''
    with open(image, 'rb') as f:
        binValue = f.read(1)
        while len(binValue) != 0:
            hexVal = hex(ord(binValue))
            string += ', ' + hexVal
            binValue = f.read(1)
    return string
```

К сожалению, я получаю в HEX, color palett, байты картинки и информацию о ней (размер и т.д.).

Помогите разобрать это на 3 разных "слоя" -
collor palett, байты картики и информацию.

Comment: 1) Как уже пытались решить проблему, что не получилось?
2) В каком формате картинка? 
3) Почему читаете её сами. а не при помощи какой-нибудь библиотекой?

Comment: @Arnial 1. Пробовал я не много, ибо просто нет представления. 2. BMP 3. Пробовал читать документации по PIL, но так и не понял, как его использовать для этого.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Используется Pillow v3.1.1 (форк PIL)

```
from PIL import Image

img = Image.open( "test_image.bmp", 'r' ) # создаст картинку из файла
img.load()                                # форсировать чтение файла
print( img.format, img.size, img.mode )   # данные по файлу   

if img.mode != 'RGB':          # bmp может по разному кодировать цвета
                               # если используется режим 
                               # отличный от RGB, то в данных будут
                               # либо индекс палитры (mode=p)
                               # либо оттенок серого (один байт на пиксель mode=L)
                               # либо ещё что то (mode=1 у меня нет такой картинки)

    img = img.convert( 'RGB' ) # сконвертирует эти форматы в 'RGB'

pixels = img.getdata()                    # получить пиксели (возвращает класс `ImagingCore`)
pix3 = list( pixels )[0:3]                # первые 3 пикселя
print([ hex( (r << 16) + (g << 8) + b ) for r,g,b in pix3 ])  #hex первых пикселей
```

UPDATE:

```
 def print_hex( path ):
    img = Image.open( path, 'r' )
    img.load()

    # палитру можно получить так (не все картинки имеют палитру)
    palette = img.getpalette() # вернёт массив в виде [r,g,b,r,g,b...] или None
    hex_palette = []
    if palette:
        hex_palette = [ hex( color_component ) for color_component in palette ]

    if img.mode == 'P':
        # изображения которые используют палитру
        # хранят цвета в виде индексов палитры
        # в таком случае hex пикселей можно получить так.
        pixels = list( img.getdata() )
        hex_palette_pixels = [ hex( pix ) for pix in pixels ]


    if img.mode != 'RGB':
        # если нужно получать цвет пикселя в rgb формате (как он будет выглядеть на экране)
        # то можно сконвертировать картинку из палитровой в RGB
        img = img.convert( 'RGB' )
        pixels = list( img.getdata() )

    hex_rgb_pixels = [ [ hex( r ),  hex( g ), hex( b ) ] for r,g,b in pixels ]
    hex_rgb_pixels_merged = [ color_component for color in hex_rgb_pixels for color_component in color ]

    print( hex_palette_pixels[0:100], hex_rgb_pixels[0: 100], hex_palette[0:100] )
```

Comment: завтра попробую и посмотрю, смогу ли я придти к результату

Comment: при выполнения последний команды - hex первых пикселей, питон выдает ошибку. `'int' object is not iterable`

Comment: Тоесть `list( pixels )[0:3]` вернул вам `int`? Не  предатсалвяю как такое возмнжно. Можете добавить номер версии питона, pil и текущий код получения хекса в вопрос?

Comment: Ну вообще у меня показывает на 10 строку - `print([ hex( (r << 16) + (g << 8) + b ) for r,g,b in pix3 ])`. Версия Python 2.7.9, версия Pillow - 2.6.1. Пытаюсь обновить на Raspberry Pi, получаю ошибку. Удалить также не возможно.

Comment: Возможно понял причину. В зависимости от типа bmp файла (черно белый,оттенки серого, палитра, кпи) в pixels могут быть разные данные.
Вариант который в ответе будет работать только для RGB формата.

Comment: Мой файл цветной и содержит все 256 цветов

Comment: Дополил код ответа. Добавил конвертирование в RGB.

Comment: Скорее всего все цвета находятся в палитре файла (она какраз может вмещать максимум 256 цветов). Палитру можно получить так: `img.palette`, в данных содержится индекс цвета в палитке, реальный цвет будет `[img.palette.getcolor( color ) for color in pix3 ]`. Но проще будет сконвертировать в RGB.

Comment: получил 0xfefffc.. что немного странно ) Причем без разницы, сколько пикселей я выбрал)

Comment: Давайте [продолжим обсуждение в чате](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/42705/discussion-between-insider-and-arnial).

Comment: Подскажите, 0:100 -  это сколько пикселей выбрано для показа? Если да, то как выбрать все, что на картинке?

Comment: `hex_rgb_pixels[0:100]` - 100 пикселей в формате rgb, для всех просто уберите слайс: `hex_rgb_pixels`

Comment: еще не понимаю немного разницу между `hex_palette_pixels`, `hex_rgb_pixels`...

Comment: У bmp есть несколько способов представления [пикселей](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/BMP#.D0.91.D0.B8.D1.82.D0.BD.D0.BE.D1.81.D1.82.D1.8C_.D0.B8.D0.B7.D0.BE.D0.B1.D1.80.D0.B0.D0.B6.D0.B5.D0.BD.D0.B8.D1.8F_.28.D0.BF.D0.BE.D0.BB.D0.B5_BitCount.29). Т.к. Ваш фаил имеет палитру то каждый пиксель кодируется одним байтом, байт содержит индэкс цвета в палитре. `hex_palette_pixels` это hex'ы "номеров цветов" пикселей (то как пиксели представлены в файле), `hex_rgb_pixels` это hex'ы "цветов" пикселей (реальные цвета пикселей).

Comment: Пытаюсь удалить  [ ] из строк, не получается, не подскажите как это сделать в этом случае?

Comment: Давайте вернёмся в чат

Comment: Не могли бы вы мне помочь дальше?

Comment: Могу попробовать, но SPI и железе не разбираюсь. Только если есть вопросы по python или pil.